# Where can I find plug-ins for Resharper?

Tags: plugins, resharper

does anyone know of a good place to find plugins for Resharper? Preferably somewhere more structured than Google...   Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[ReSharper Gallery](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/) contains a number of packages.

Answer (score 4):

There are some more [here](http://resharper.blogspot.com/2008/04/extending-extension-resharper-plug-ins.html).

Answer (score 1):

In partial (self) answer, the list at the Resharper site itself is a good start. Is there anywhere discussing the available plugins, and which ones are worthwile?